# Is it possible to use firebase to do web scraping with the free account?

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a custom API for my android application. The idea is to make in app a http-request to the site that generates on deploying cloud functions, which in theory have to do a web scraping.

Is this possible in a Firebase project on the free plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to perform web scraping using cloud functions.

The free firebase account doesn't permit you to make external requests (such as to another website) without enabling billing. You can see their pricing models pertaining to your needs at https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (search for "Outbound networking" on the page)

Comment: Recommendations for offsite services are off-topic for Stack Overflow, as they may be considered spam.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, since Cloud Functions requires a payment plan in order to contact sites outside of Google's control.  This is described in the [pricing plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) in the question mark hover for Cloud Functions.

Recommendations for off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to spam anyone, but I really didn't know where to ask this question...